# Comparing the running of a linked list and a custom linked list

Tags: java

It's a homework assignment, and it's not that hard, it's just my understanding could be flawed.

So I have two linked lists: a **doubly linked list and a custom linked list**. There are only two functions that we are concerned with: **void add()** and **boolean contains()**.

MyLinkedList extends AbstractList and the functions are untouched, but the custom linkedList extends MyLinkedList and **overrides the contains()** method such that when an element is looked up, it will always be moved to the front of the list, you know, to improve lookup times for more frequently used words.

It also overrides the **add()** method such that items are not added to the back of the list but to the front of it.

And I have a **dictionary.txt file** which is a dictionary which contains (~10000 words).

What the program does is create a MyLinkedList object and a custom linkedlist object and adds the **dictionary.txt** words to the respective list. So that should mean that in MyLinkedList the words are in order while in the custom linkedlist they are in reverse order.

Then the program takes in a txt file e.g. romeo-and-juliet.txt and traverses the first 10000 words of that txt file if the words match the words in the MyLinkedList object and does a separate run for the custom linkedlist object.

**Q:** Why does the custom linkedlist one run faster than MyLinkedList? My answer is that since the custom linkedlist moves frequently used search terms to the front, the lookup times are shorter, so it will run faster than MyLinkedList. I hope my answer sounds good, feel free to improve it.

Now the puzzling one is that now we are using romeo-and-juliet.txt as the dictionary file itself, this is what happens:

i.e. shortest time to longest time:

1. MyLinkedList using romeo-and-juliet dictionary ~80ms
2. custom list on dictionary.txt ~160ms
3. MyLinkedList on dictionary.txt ~360ms
4. custom list on romeo-and-juliet dictionary ~390ms

**Q:** Why is this so? If we are using only the words of the story as the scope of the dictionary, why is it slower for the custom linkedlist?

P.S. if there is any part of the question that is unclear, please feel free to tell me and I'll edit anything that I left out.

Comment: When you use R&J as the dictionary, do you sort it and/or remove duplicate words or just use the raw text?

Comment: I believe duplicates are not removed because the add() function does remove duplicates for either linkedlist class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the custom list always adds words to the front, the dictionary will be in the reverse order of how the terms were read in.  For the normal dictionary that won't make much of a difference, but when you use the text of Romeo and Juliet itself as the dictionary, this is what you'll end up with:

`Romeo and Juliet`: "Two households, both alike in dignity ... Than this of Juliet and her Romeo."

`MyLinkedList`: "Two", "households", "both", "alike", "in", "dignity", ...

`custom list`: "Romeo", "her", "and", "Juliet", "of", "this", "Than", ...

Since you are searching for the text of R&J in order, when you search against `MyLinkedList` with the R&J dictionary, the first word will always be found in the first position, the second word will always found be found in the second position and so on, as the *worst possible* lookup, or faster if the word has already appeared in the play.

That is much, *much* faster than looking each word up in a normal dictionary.

---

Now let's consider what happens when you start searching against `custom list`.  The first word you are searching for is that very last word in the dictionary, or earlier if it appears more than once in the play.  However it is certainly going to take longer to find it than when you searched against `MyLinkedList`.  Then, to make matters worse, you move that word to the front of the dictionary, pushing the 'known' location of the second word to the very end of the dictionary, right before you search for it.  This will be somewhat mitigated as common words (e.g. "a", "the", "and") bubble up to the front, but it won't overcome the massive advantage that the `MyLinkedList` search had.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I can visualise it now. Thank you!